# Why does this code create a new TableColumn instead of populating the existing one defined in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I suppose this is less about actually needing to design a column in FXML but more about understanding how the FXML and controller class interact.
So i've defined a table in FXML like this:

```
<TableView fx:id="UserList" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="200.0"     prefWidth="200.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Profile" fx:id="ProfileNameColumn" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

And want to fill it with the name of users from a method in the main class called getUsers() which I do like this:

```
    @FXML private TableView<User> UserList;
    @FXML private TableColumn<User, String> ProfileNameColumn;

public void setApp(EncryptSyncGui application){
        this.application = application;
        ObservableList<User> data = FXCollections.observableList(application.getUsers());
       ProfileNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Profile");
        ProfileNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("name"));
        UserList.getColumns().add((TableColumn<User, String>) ProfileNameColumn);

        UserList.setItems(data);
    }
```

But instead of filling in the existing column with fx:ID ProfileNameColumn it makes a brand new column. To define the column in FXML would I also have to populate it in FXML? If so how would I call the method from the main class in FXML?
Pre-emptive thanks.

Comment: You actually create a new column - nothing suprising. Try, instead of ProfileNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Profile");, write ProfileNameColumn = UserList.getColumns().get(0); and remove UserList.getColumns().add((TableColumn<User, String>) ProfileNameColumn); or smth like that. btw, field of class should start from low letter : userList, profileNameColumn....

Comment: Thank you for your help this worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice about class Fields although it did cost me about half an hour as I forgot to refactor the fx:id values in the FXML file, d'oh.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a new column is created - nothing suprising.

Try, instead of

```
ProfileNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Profile");
```

write

```
ProfileNameColumn = UserList.getColumns().get(0);
```

and remove

```
UserList.getColumns().add((TableColumn<User, String>) ProfileNameColumn);
```